# SDL2 ios How to get UIViewController pointer

Tags: c++, ios, uiviewcontroller, uikit, sdl

I'm making a mobile game with SDL2 which will be initially developed for IOS.

I have almost finnished the game development, and now, in order to integrate it with Firebase, I need a pointer to UIViewController.

After reading countless topics, I tried this:

```
SDL_SysWMinfo systemWindowInfo;
SDL_VERSION (& systemWindowInfo.version);
SDL_GetWindowWMInfo (sdlWindow, & systemWindowInfo))
UIWindow * appWindow = mainWindowWMInfo.info.uikit.window;
UIViewController * rootViewController = appWindow.rootViewController;
```

But the line "UIViewController * rootViewController = appWindow.rootViewController;" causes this error: "Incomplete definition of type '_UIWindow'"

All topics related to this sample code are at least four years old, and I'm trying hard, but I haven't found any topics talking recently about how to get UIViewController in an SDL2 / ios project.

So, my questions are:

1. Is the sample code above still working in the current versions of SDL2 or has something changed in the latest version and this sample code no longer works?
2. If the sample code still works, what can I do wrong to cause this “Incomplete definition of type '_UIWindow'” error?
3. If this sample code no longer works in SDL2, how can I get a UIViewController pointer in the current version of SDL2?

Any help is welcome because I have been stuck in this problem for days. I've been working on this game for ten months and solving this problem is the last task left to complete it , so I really need to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. Everything is OK in SDL, I was using a .cpp file in this code, but I needed to use .mm file here.

So, when I switched the file name from cpp to mm, the problem has solved.